# numpy linear algebra on diagonal arrays without explicit duplication

Tags: python, numpy, array-broadcasting

I have an array `w` (shape `(3000, 100, 100)`) which I want to multiply with another array `e` (shape `(5, 3000)`) such that the result `k` has shape `(5, 5, 100, 100)` and

```
k[:, :, i, j] = e @ np.diag(w[:, i, j]) @ e.T
```

Since `w` is so large, it's not practical to make some `super_w` array with shape `(3000, 3000, 100, 100)` and explicitly populate the main diagonal. It is also not terribly efficient to loop over `i` and `j`. Is there a memory-efficient way to do this, other than breaking up `w` into chunks?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With [`np.einsum`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.einsum.html) -

```
k = np.einsum('li,ijk,mi->lmjk',e,w,e)
```

Comment: had no idea this was possible with einsum!